# Google Cloud Build specify firebase site id when deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am facing an issue where i need to deploy a staging site from Google Cloud Build.

I added another site under the same firebase project, meaning now I have 2 site under the same project.
[image]

This is my cloudbuild.yaml file

```
    steps :
  - name : node
    entrypoint : npm
    args :
      - ci
  - name : node
    entrypoint : npm
    args :
      - run
      - build
  - name : asia.gcr.io/$_project_id/firebase
    args :
      - deploy
      - --project=xxxxxxxxx
      - --only=hosting
```

Is there any way that I can specify the site id in cloudbuild.yaml file

Comment: It seems that this feature is not yet available. It would be best to reach out to [Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) or file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for this feature to be available in the future. We don't have ETA for this.